# Accessing a variable from different classes

Tags: java, android, class

there is 2 classes; the `MainActivity` and `SimpleFLashLighImpl`.
In `MainActivity` class, I have put a code to get a string from an edit box 'no'
and then convert it into an integer 'intdelay'.
This is MainActivity part of code:

```
    public static volatile int intdelay = 1000;






   textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    delay=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edttxt);

    String no=delay.getText().toString();       //this will get a string
    try{
        MainActivity.intdelay = Integer.parseInt(no);
    }catch(NumberFormatException ex){ // handle your exception
    }

    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView.setText(delay.getText());
        }
    });
```

in the other class I am trying to access the 'intdelay' int value to make a delay using handler. 
This is the other class part of code:

```
 public void switchFlash() {
       final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            if (isFlashOn()) {
                turnOffFlash();
                x++;      
            } else if (x>10) {
                turnOffFlash();
            }
            else
            {
                turnOnFlash();
             }
             handler.postDelayed(this, MainActivity.intdelay);

           }
       };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable,MainActivity.intdelay);
}
```

But the problem is that each time I am getting the delay of 1000 that is initialized at the beginning of `MainActivity` class.
What could the solution be?

Comment: There is no statement that changes the class variable `intdelay`, so it always stays at the initial value of 1000. Maybe the statement `int intdelay = Integer.parseInt(no)` was intended to change it, but it introduces a block local variable instead that leaves the class variable untouched. But even if you remove the type declaration, it might not do what you want because the action seems to take place in the `onClick` method of the button, where you you again do not touch the class variable.

Answer (score 1):

You never change the value of intdelay. `MainActivity.intdelay = Integer.parseInt(no);` does compare, not change. Use `==` to set the new value.
You also should declare your variables private and build getter/setter methods.
You should also consider to move your delay variables into your Runnable if not needed elsewhere.

Comment: Is this question solved? Then mark it as solved please.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `intdelay` variable, instead of modifying the static variable declared:

```
int intdelay = Integer.parseInt(no);
```

should be

```
MainActivity.intdelay = Integer.parseInt(no);
```

Once you fix that, you will run into memory visibility issues. Changes made by one thread are not guaranteed to be visible to other threads unless you use some form of synchronization.

I would suggest marking the `intdelay` variable as `volatile`:

```
public static volatile int intdelay = 1000;
```

Comment: @Aloweiwi can you update your question with the updated code?

Comment: OK, looks good, it should work. Can you check that the following code is being called and `intdelay` is being updated by your text input: `MainActivity.intdelay = Integer.parseInt(no);`?

Comment: how can I check that ?

Comment: I don't know android that well, but you should be able to log a message before and after this statement: `MainActivity.intdelay = Integer.parseInt(no);` and then view the output using `adb logcat`? Also log the value of `no` that you are getting from your editbox.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your code is throwing exception and going into catch statement, so the default value will still be the same which is 1000. Check your

```
int intdelay = Integer.parseInt(no);
```

use logd/toast to check what value you are trying to parse. Like this
if in Activity class

```
try{
        int intdelay = Integer.parseInt(no);
    }catch(NumberFormatException ex){ // handle your exception
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this(),"no is: "+ no,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: then replace getContext() with your activity name something like this, MainActivity().this

Comment: It causes the app to crash before starting

Comment: recopy, the code and check the value of your  'no', are you getting string or integer or even long type?

Answer (score 0):

**why u not declare delay in runnable ?**

see my answer is talking about runnable post loop

[What will happen if I use try catch and finally for handler using runnable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37957863/what-will-happen-if-i-use-try-catch-and-finally-for-handler-using-runnable/37958048#37958048)

example:

```
   final Handler handler = new Handler();
   handler.post(new Runnable() {

    // this int will also be passed to method post delayed 
    // as "this" keyword applies to Anonymous Class 
    // which body contains everything between brackets of new Runnable() { ... }
    int withThisDelay = 1000;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.postDelayed(this,withThisDelay);
        withThisDelay += 1000;
    }
});
```

you can extend(implement) runnable as own class(abstract without run) (with getter / setter) and then define this runnable as variable and use it

```
 public abstract class MyIntRunnable implements Runnable {

      int _myDelay  = 1000;
      // to get delay 
      public int getDelay() { return _myDelay; }
      // to set delay
      public void setDelay(int myDelay) { _myDelay = myDelay; } 

 }
```

then use :

**ClassA**

```
 private final static MyRunnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable() {

      @Override
       public void run() {

           // post with var delayed 
           Handler.postDelayed(this,getDelay())

       }
 }
 // get delay from runnable 
 myRunnable.setDelay(2000);
 // set delay to runnable
 int myDelayFromRunnable = myDelay.getDelay();
```

**ClassB**

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // get string from edit text 
        String getDelayString = delay.getText();
        // prevent null values or empty string 
        // you should use catch numberformat exception here 
        // this mean check if text is not null and is not empty 
        // if empty or null set to 1000  else try parse to int 
        int delay = getDelayString != null && !getDelayString.isEmpty() 
                        ? Integer.parseImnt(getDelayString) : 1000;
        // set delay in static runnable in other class
        ClassA.myRunnable.setDelay(delay);
    }
});
```

example use catch of NumberFormatException

```
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(.....);

// we can define this as method and use in on click listener 
private void myParseMethod(EditText editText) {
    try {
        String stringDelay = editText.getText().toString();
        // if parsing was successful
        ClassA.myRunnable.setDelay(stringDelay);;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nxe) {
        // inform user 
        editText.setError("Bad integer!!!");
    }
}
```